# Will Cyanogenmod run apps that are built using Android Studio?

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I'd like to switch to CyanogenMod from Android 4.4. Will I be able to use the device to run apps,coded using Android Studio after doing the same?

Comment: yes you will be able to do so

Comment: This question is not for StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes, it will run in CyanogenMod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CyanogenMod is an aftermarket firmware for a number of cell phones based on the open-source Android operating system. It offers features not found in the official Android based firmwares of vendors of these cell phones.

> To ask how CyanogenMod is different from Android is comparable to ask
>   How is a cat different from an animal. CyanogenMod is an Android
>   custom-rom

**So the answer is yes!**

Comment: This does not seems an answer, you could have said that in comment. But as you have a lovely dp i'll upvote your comment type answer :P

Comment: Well @SyedAliSalman and @M David thankyou for the compliment, but it is the correct answer and answer deserves to be in answer's place not in comment's.

Comment: @Salmaan well this was the second reason i up-voted your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unless the device doesn't have Google Play Services installed and your app require any of that kind of feature.

Comment: The "pure" Android (AOSP) doesn't have Google Play Services either so this doesn't differentiate between CyanogenMod and Android. You flash the GApps for CyanogenMod in the same way you do for AOSP. Original Post does not specify AOSP or OEM Android bundled with Play Services